# Translate into Arabic (Localization) issue

Tags: java, android, localization, multilingual, arabic-support

I'm trying to make my app support Arabic & English languages

i did it but it's not working well in some android version idk which of them...

[this working well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnR53.png)

[but this not working well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1dJW.jpg)

I'm using the following code to in the oncreate of the mean activity of the app

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String localLanguage = MySingleton.getmInstance(this).getAppLang();
    if (localLanguage.equals(getString(R.string.settings_language_arabic_value))) {
        Locale localeAr = new Locale("ar");
        setLocale(localeAr, getString(R.string.settings_language_arabic_value));
    } else if (localLanguage.equals(getString(R.string.settings_language_english_value))) {
        Locale localeEn = new Locale("en");
        setLocale(localeEn, getString(R.string.settings_language_english_value));
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_branches);
    .......
    .......
 }

 private void setLocale(Locale locale, String lang) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        if (lang.equals(getString(R.string.settings_language_arabic_value)))
            config.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("ar"));
        else config.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("en"));
        getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    } else {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        if (lang.equals(getString(R.string.settings_language_arabic_value)))
            config.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("ar"));
        else config.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("en"));
        Locale.setDefault(config.locale);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

if any one can give me a hand he will made my day 
thanks in advance

Comment: add the localized text after opening pop-up screen or pass the language that you want to access the word. Hope this will work.

Comment: the problem not in the pop-up screen ...
if you noticed tabs and activity title not translated too and layoutdirection didn't change @HirenRathod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I figured a solution ..

will share it if any one want it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String localLanguage = MySingleton.getmInstance(this).getAppLang();
    if (localLanguage.equals(getString(R.string.settings_language_arabic_value))) {
        setLocale("ar", this);
    } else if (localLanguage.equals(getString(R.string.settings_language_english_value))) {
        Locale localeEn = new Locale("en");
        setLocale("en", this);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_branches);
    .........
    .........
}
```

the change in code is here:

```
private void setLocale(String lang, Context context) {
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

I hope this help anyone